# Fill a list with a dictionary key in a specific order in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a letter and a coordinate, as follow:

```
alfacor = {'a': [1, 1], 'c': [1, 3], 'b': [1, 2]...}
```

Then I have a list in the next format

```
final_list = [[2, 2], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 3], [3, 3], [1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Finally a for loop should do the trick, but aparently I am missing something

```
for l, c in alfacor.iteritems():
    if c in final_list:
        encripta_f.append(l)
```

output

```
['a', 'c', 'd', 'g', 'o', 'n', 'p', 's']
```

Expected output

```
[g, o, p, s, n, a, d, c, o]
```

I see that `final_list` it's been set in the folowing order and also repeated items are been ignore, any ideas in how to get the expected output

```
[[1, 1], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 2], [3, 4], [3, 3], [3, 5], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: post the exact input. What's your final expected output?

Comment: What's the value of `alfacor` variable?

Comment: the extact input is: `final_list = [[2, 2], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 3], [3, 3], [1, 1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [3, 4]]` . I'd like to iterate `final_list` over my dictionarie's value (`alfacor`)  so that I can  get every key correspondig  to that specific coordinate(`final_list`) in the `final_list` order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries in Python don't have a defined iteration order, whether you iterate the keys directly (`for key in some_dict:`), or using `items()` or `iteritems()`. If you want to iterate the dictionary in a particular order, you have to do so yourself.

In this case, it looks like you want the keys in the order of the elements from `final_list` that they correspond to? If so, you'll want to iterate the `final_list`, and check whether each of its values is a value in `alfacor`, and then output the corresponding key.

To do this, you have to invert the dictionary. (This is only safe if you don't have any duplicate values in the dictionary, which I can't tell if you do or don't here. FYI.)

To do this, you need to have values in the dictionary which are hashable (basically, they must be immutable). Tuples will do the trick, but tuples aren't equal to lists with the same contents:

```
>>> [1, 2] == (1, 2)
False
```

So you'll need to convert the elements in `final_list` to tuples, too, to get equality to work.

All together, something like this should do the trick:

```
# invert the `alfacor` dict, and conver its
# values to tuples which are hashable
inv_alfacor = {}
for letter, coordinate in alfacor.iteritems():
    inv_alfacor[tuple(coordinate)] = letter

# now build the output list in the order of the
# input list, converting the coordinates from
# final_list to tuples since lists and tuples
# are never equal
encripta_f = []
for element in final_list:
    element = tuple(element)
    if element in inv_alfacor:
        encripta_f.append(inv_alfacor[element])
```